# How to store part of a field value in another column in SQL

Tags: sql, substr, self-join

So I'm trying to get a part of a value from a column and insert that part into another column - new column. BOTH columns are in the same table. So what i want should look something like this:

```
id      newColumn      oldColumn
1       12             123 some text
2       24             246 some text
....
```

I know how to get 12 and 24 using SUBSTR, but how do i enter the data for each row in the table. Should i be using self-join or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add new col using following command:-

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_NAME
ADD COLUMN COL_NAME(VARCHAR(10));
```

After that execute this command:-

```
UPDAET TAB_NAME
SET COL_NAME = SUBSTRING(OLDCOLUMN, 1, 2);
```

I think this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

No need to join, it's just a plain `UPDATE`:

```
update tablename set newColumn = substring(oldColumn from 1 for 2)
```

`substring` is ANSI SQL, some dbms have substr and other versions.

The question is why you are doing this? What do you expect to find in newColumn if someone later updates oldColumn to another value? Maybe you should have a view instead, where newColumn always has up to date values?

Answer (score 0):

Please get into the habit of ALWAYS specifying the DB engine you are using... It helps us to help you - we can provide more relevant answers.

You might want to consider using a calculated column as opposed to storing the information again.

In SQL Server you could do something like this

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD new_column as SUBSTRING(old_column, 1, 2);
```

This way you don't need to insert or update this column it is always consistent with the original column. and you just use it in your select statement in the usual way.

```
select new_column from YourTable
```